# Replacing a value in a column using REPLACE is not working

Tags: sql-server

I have this select:

```
  select * from phrase where english like 'command%'
```

it returns:

```
  command; to tell (to do); to order; to charge; to direct; to tell on (someone); to report; to often say
```

I am trying to replace all the occurences of "; to" with "; " so I issued this command:

```
   update phrase set english = replace(english, ';to ', '; ')
```

It tells me when I run this that every row in the table changed but when I check the data it didn't do anything and the string returned from that first select is just the same. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Your `UPDATE` has a typo.  The call to `REPLACE()` should look like this: `REPLACE(english, '; to', ';')`  The phrase `;to` never appears in the sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string containing space `; to`. But in your update there is no space in between ; & to.

So try this

```
   update phrase set english = replace(english, '; to ', '; ')
```

Comment: Typically typo questions should not be answered, unless there is information would be useful to other people.  In this case, I don't think there is.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to add the space between `;` and `to`.